# Install a VirtualBox with a commandline attached iso

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, iso-image

I have created a VirtualBox, that has not yet an OS installed. If I attach a bootable iso file with OS installer via GUI->settings->network and start the box per gui or per VBoxManage, the OS is properly installed from the iso file. If I attach the same iso with *VBoxManage storageattach* the installation fails with 'No bootable medium found!' error when stated via GUI, or with:

```
VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'BAD' has terminated unexpectedly during startup because of signal 6
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
```

when started with VBoxManage startvm. 
The output of 'VBoxManage  showvminfo' for the dvd device is identical in both cases.
How is the correct way to install an OS with command line?

Comment: Are you sure they're identical? Can you `diff` the outputs of the two ways to performed the attach? So if you're using a bash-like shell, `VBoxManage showvminfo BAD > info.gui` with the GUI attach and `VBoxManage showvminfo BAD > info.cli` with the command-line attach and then `diff info.gui info.cli` to find any differences. Similarly, is the result the same using `VBoxManage showmediuminfo`?

Comment: Only some names and UUIDs differ, 'IDE (1, 0): /home/unittest/Candidates.iso/X.iso (UUID: d3c8a4e2-b3ee-46c6-8d03-bb70cddc18e4)' is idendical in both cases